# Why can't I install python packages with pip on windows 10?

Tags: python, pip, operating-system, windows-10

I have had this running battle with pip on my windows 10 PC ever since I tried to upgrade it. I tried to upgrade it with `pip upgrade`. After that, pip has stopped working. I wanted to install Pygame on my pc with `pip install pygame` and I got the following error message about my operating system:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Python310\\Include\\pygame'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I get the same error message anytime I try to install any python package on my pc. Please what can I do to correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

1. Run Windows PowerShell as Admin
2. Run the pip install command to install the python module or upgrade the pip.

---- OR ----

**Solution #2**

Run Pip Install with `--user` flag

Command: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user`

Answer (score 0):

Just type the command you want execute with the user permission, if you don't want to change the permission:

```
pip install pygame --user
```

and if you want to change user permission then follow these steps:

Just *change the access permission*, where the particular package is going to install.

On **Windows 10**:

- Go to the installation folder. For example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37`
- Right click on python installation root and click `Properties`. In this case, the `Python37` folder.
- Go to the `Security` tab, click `Edit` button and allow **full control** for the **Users** group. Remember to click `Apply`.
- Try to install the package again.

Below is an example of desired settings:
[image]